# Is it possible to have an offline database

Tags: php, javascript, sql, database

Short Story: I downloaded a java/flash uploader and one of the files was a .db. After some research I found that is a database. Which prompted the question. Can I make a database (.db) file and save it in a folder in my root directory instead of having to rely on another server and sql query's? Thereby theoretically speeding up my website by accessing only local files.

The Problem: I have done lots of research and found no answer. Mainly I think because I have never dealt with this before so i don't know where to look.

The Question: Has anyone ever heard of such a thing? And if so, could you refer me to a tutorial website or provide a brief definition/ explanation/ example of how this would work and what type of communication language would be used between the files? SQL? something else? I just don't know!

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I'd suggest using sqlite. It uses a local file database and is the easiest to get up to speed with. However, be careful thinking that this will speed things up.

Comment: Say "hello" to [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/).

Comment: if your database is on the same server, basically all it does is storing your data in a subfolder of your root's directory. Did you mean you wanted to store the data at the client's side or at the location the php files are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[The good part]**
Theoretically, yes, you can do it. One example would be [sqlite database](http://www.sqlite.org/).  This database is a single file that you store wherever you want.  If you're coding in PHP, you'll need to have the corresponding extension installed with your PHP to access/query this database.

**[The bad part**]
This only makes sense if you're dealing with small amounts of data and your queries are relatively simple.  Sqlite databases are slow and support only a limited set of sql operations.  They also don't have support for many standard datatypes and lack a lot of built-in functions that you may rely on.  Sqlite databases are very good if you want a simple db support in a standalone app (e.g. mobile application with local data), but not very good for storing large amounts of transactional data.

**[The verdict]**
If you're looking to speed up your web application, switching from a proper database to sqlite will probably only hinder your app, not help it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That seems to be what everyone is telling me. Looks like I'm sticking with the database I have and keep searching for speed bottleneck

Comment: @pure_code I'm not sure what your comment refers to. You can have sqlite on either client or server if needed - all depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

SQLlite can provide a database that works without using a server. It provides a standard SQL interface like you would use with a reguar sql server (MySQL etc). Its probably not going to be faster as it will rely on a lot more disk I/O than a standard database server.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I saw SQLlite in my research but thought it was the same thing as mySQL. I'll look into it, but if it offers no speed increase, then there doesn't seem to be any benefit to using it. I'll probably stick with my mySQL database.

Comment: Memory access is way faster than disk access. If your MySQL server is properly configured and your queries and tables are optimized, you will see dramatically better performance with MySQL.

Comment: @datasage that's an odd comparison to make since both provide "in-memory databases".

Comment: @salathe If you are using SQLlite to persist data, you are not likely using an in-memory database. I suppose there are some uses cases for it, but not very common.

Answer (score 0):

[SQlite](http://www.sqlite.org) is serverless. It's well documented. PHP has an [extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php) to work with it too. But if you really want to speed things up you should look at [memcached](http://memcached.org/), [redis](http://redis.io/), [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) and such.

Answer (score 0):

What I really think you're asking about is a flat file database.

http://www.databasedev.co.uk/flatfile-vs-rdbms.html

Comment: That seems to be what i found with the .db file. But from that link you sent. It seems pretty useless. I think I'll stay away from them.

Answer (score 0):

Almost any database solution that you can name relies on files as the storage mechanism, so just having data stored in a file does not convey any inherent performance bonus to your application.  Server-less databases like SQLite do exist, but the reasons for selecting them rarely have to do with performance, but rather portability.

You can run local instances of MySQL or other databases to eliminate the over-the-wire transmission cost. If properly configured they would outperform something like SQLite in most every case, as MySQL relies on in-memory storage in addition to on-disk storage.

Since it sounds like you are pretty new to this sort of stuff, I would give a word of caution about trying to worry about these sort of premature performance optimizations.  Perhaps start with a traditional relational database (like MySQL) on the same server as your web server.

Once you get to the point where you have enough traffic to where you need to separate the database onto a different server (to allocate more resources to either the database or the web application, or to be able to allow for multiple load-balanced web application servers talking to a single backend database) then you can start worrying more about these sorts of performance tweaks.

Comment: Thank you. Traffic isn't really my concern right now. I already have a mySQL database set up and running on another server. I was looking into alternatives because the only two semi-big parts of the website are a simple gallery that takes the location of the folder from the SQL database and displays four per row and organizes them by album. I also have a calendar that uses javascript and php to set itself up properly and takes events from the SQL database and puts them on the right date. Both of which are running horribly slowly. I guess the problem isn't with the database though.

Comment: @KyleRoseberry The problem could very well be with the database and/or your queries.  The have to make sure your queries a utilizing properly created indexes.  You need to make sure your MySQL server has enough resources allocated to it (HINT: the default MySQL config is oftentimes horribly configured with regards to memory allocation) so as to keep your indexes in memory and so forth.  If you have problematic queries, you should open up separate questions on them to help get improvements.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you are talking about is simply running a server on the same computer where the client is.  That of course is possible.

The advantage is that it would still use SQL, and even network protocols, but be self contained on the same computer.  Later switching to a production environment would be a minimal configuration change.

It would not actually use the network, but would instead would make all the network calls in memory.  This would run very fast, and is a good development environment.